# PHPExcel: print page margins and print auto fit seems not working

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm calling these 3 functions one after other in this exact order

```
public function setPrintFitToWidth()
{
    $this->sheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(1);    
}

public function setPrintArea($cell_area)
{
    $this->sheet->getPageSetup()->setPrintArea($cell_area); 
}

public function setPrintMargins($top, $right, $bottom, $left)
{
    $this->sheet->getPageMargins()->setTop($top);
    $this->sheet->getPageMargins()->setRight($right);
    $this->sheet->getPageMargins()->setLeft($left);
    $this->sheet->getPageMargins()->setBottom($bottom);
}
```

The problem is that, opening resulting Excel file, I've page margin set to 'custom' but, in fact, set to different values instead of margin I passed to my function. In fact I called with argument `(1,0.5,0.5,1)` but I got, in the same orders, `2, 0.8, 0.8, 2`. It's really strange ...

Also: I cannot get working `setFittoWidth(1)`; I expect to see adapted for all column in one page, but Excel tell me It's setup on adapt sheet on a page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What Writer are you using?

Comment: The default. I think it's Excel2007, because I create `.xlsx` files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolved:

changed

```
public function setPrintFitToWidth()
{
    $this->sheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(1);    
}
```

to

```
public function setPrintFitToWidth()
{
    $this->sheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToWidth(1);    
    $this->sheet->getPageSetup()->setFitToHeight(0);    
}
```

About the margins: I tried with zero and margin are respected, so I concluded than PHPExcel unit are in someway 'scaled down'... So, after some 'try' and 'redo', I found the values that generate the correct magins

Comment: I think the page margin parameters are in inches, 1cm = 0.393 cm, if I use 0.39 as value it shows up as 10mm in Excel.